# Sketch 3: Grouped Objects appear in a larger bounding box than the objects in the group do

Tags: sketch-app, bug

Grouping Objects often adds extra width/height to the group itself. I cannot always reproduce this, but even with pixel perfect shapes (w/o half pixels and stuff) it happens that the folder is wider/higher than it’s content. If I select the content of the group separately, everything is fine. Since I’m using grouping a lot (I mean, really a lot!) to keep my file structure clear, this issue is really annoying for me, because it affects the evenly distribution of objects as well. Do you have an idea how I can fix this?

Here's an example screenshot:[image: Sketch Grouped Objects]

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Is this check mark placed via an icon font? Then converting it to an outline would fix your problem.

Comment: Hello Thomas. What version of Sketch are you using ? I remember having the same problem but I don't have it anymore, maybe fixed by an update.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Mm0wI5aNMg

I have exactly the same issue and it drives me crazy, because there is no logic behind this behaviour.

Their mechanics now works like this: if your object coordinates on X axis (for example) is round number without fractions and you trying to group it with any other object Sketch for some reason considers this object as shifted for tiny part of adjacent pixel and it thinks object is one pixel wider and includes it inside your created group (like -0). You can fix this by manually selecting your problem object and in Position field add some positive fractional value, like add 0.00001 to your object position. Done, now group your objects!

This method will somehow totally resets your object position and this bug will never occur again **with this object only**.

Weird, waiting for fix by Bohemian.